# SSL: generating a CSR for a domain with and without www on ubuntu 14.04 / apache2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-http-server

I want to create a CSR for my domain, but I was unable to find details online about this.

Is the CSR generation different when I want to use addresses with www and without on the mentioned combination?

e.g.

```
www.domain.com
domain.com
```

I am following a tutorial by from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic certificate is for a single address only.  So either

```
 www.domain.com
```

or

```
 domain.com
```

You have the option of getting two certificates, one for each domain, or getting a multi-domain certificate.  It is often the case that a multi-domain certificate is not cost-effective unless you need to cover three or four domains.

If you still want to create a multi-domain CSR you need to edit the /etc/openssl.conf file and change the req section:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
```

and add the v3_req section:

```
[v3_req]
subjectAltName=DNS:www.domain.com,DNS:domain.com
```

It is worth putting both variants into the subjectAltName as well as entering the common name as domain.com, as the common name is sometimes ignored if the subjectAltName is present.

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell how the actual generation goes or point me to a relevant documentation?

Comment: Once you make these changes, you run through the same process as in the tutorial, but the CSR generated will have the extra names in it.  For more info, google `openssl multi host`

Comment: Note that various CAs have started recommending that `subjectAltName` be used _exclusively_, so the "basic" subject CN is no longer the primary source of information; it is only used for compatibility with very old clients.